# OS X Yosemite - Too many files open

Tags: macos, homebrew, osx-yosemite

I recently upgraded from Mavericks to Yosemite....headaches ensued

**I'm pretty sure my problem lies w/ the number of files I can open** - ***but I'm not sure how to solve it***.  I'm also pretty sure I've read every article/tip about creating the `/etc/sysctl.conf` file and `/etc/launchd.conf` file

For clarity's sake this is what both of them currently look like n.b. (I'm not even sure if these are the right commands to put in them anymore - I've tried just about everything and every combination. ie: higher values, lower values, removing commands, adding commands)

**/etc/launchd.conf**

```
limit maxfiles 16384 32768
limit maxproc 1000 2000
```

**/etc/sysctl.conf**

```
# Turn up maxproc
kern.maxproc=2048
# Turn up the maxproc per user
kern.maxprocperuid=512
```

I've also tried increasing my ulimit values - both globally and locally for my current session...no bueno

**ulimit -a**

```
-t: cpu time (seconds)              unlimited
-f: file size (blocks)              unlimited
-d: data seg size (kbytes)          unlimited
-s: stack size (kbytes)             8192
-c: core file size (blocks)         0
-v: address space (kbytes)          unlimited
-l: locked-in-memory size (kbytes)  unlimited
-u: processes                       709
-n: file descriptors                4096
```

Ok - this is where my headache initially started...My DB (percona-server 5.6.21-69.0 installed via homebrew) started choking and dying, and in the mysql-error.log it was filled w/ the error `too many files open`.

```
2014-10-21 15:19:50 5190 [ERROR] /usr/local/Cellar/percona-server/5.6.21-69.0/bin/mysqld: Can't open file: './ie/tokenorder_products.frm' (errno: 24 - Too many open files)
2014-10-21 15:19:50 5190 [ERROR] /usr/local/Cellar/percona-server/5.6.21-69.0/bin/mysqld: Can't open file: './ie/tokenorders.frm' (errno: 24 - Too many open files)
2014-10-21 15:19:50 5190 [ERROR] /usr/local/Cellar/percona-server/5.6.21-69.0/bin/mysqld: Can't open file: './ie/tsdevices.frm' (errno: 24 - Too many open files)
2014-10-21 15:19:50 5190 [ERROR] /usr/local/Cellar/percona-server/5.6.21-69.0/bin/mysqld: Can't open file: './ie/tsracks.frm' (errno: 24 - Too many open files)
2014-10-21 15:19:50 5190 [ERROR] /usr/local/Cellar/percona-server/5.6.21-69.0/bin/mysqld: Can't open file: './ie/v_classunity_classlist.frm' (errno: 24 - Too many open files)
2014-10-21 15:20:48 5190 [ERROR] Error in accept: Too many open files
```

This is where I initially started to try and solve that problem by "up-ing" my ulimit, maxfiles, maxproc,etc...

Eventually - frustrated, I moved on and would come back to that issue later. So then I was trying to `sudo gem install nokogiri`  and over and over it would fail and spit out this same error (a lot of repeats about the builder.rb failing to build the gem native extension - followed by a bunch of repeated stacktraces [Logs Gist](https://gist.github.com/veilig2000/ea8c9836346a9d699f69)

**nokogiri Install Errors**
[image: nokogiri install errors]

I've tried/googled a bunch of different approaches to solve this issue (ie: additional flags, etc..). Whats amazing - and when I started thinking this issue was tied to the # of files/processes open is when I checked `top` while the gem was installing....I was pretty surprised to see what I found

**top during `gem install nokogiri`**
[image: sudo gem install nokogiri]

It looks like my process keeps forking, which then made sense for this ONE line in my previous picture (see "nokogiri install errors picture")

`sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable`

So I'm kinda out of ideas, but I'm not really sure how to debug the # of files anymore?

**UPDATE**

Well, I managed to get nokogiri installed.  Unfortunately, I'm not exactly sure what fixed it b/c I've tried so many things.  But I think it had to deal w/ reinstalling ruby.  However, I'm still getting the same issue w/ my DB complaining about *too many files open* when I use any sort of database that is not trivially small.

Comment: Hm. Probably shouldn't be spawning so much? Perhaps also worth raising a bug with the devs of that gem.

Answer (score 16):

Modifying the `/etc/launchd.conf` per a lot of google queries and SO suggestions didn't seem to work for me in Yosemite (10.10).  What did end up working, after numerous change/reboot/test combinations, was modifying (or creating if it doesn't exist) the `/etc/sysctl.conf` file.

This is what I had to put in to make it work

```
kern.maxfiles=65536
kern.maxfilesperproc=65536
```

I'm not sure if `kern.maxfiles` needs to be in there, but when I had it in there by itself I still had the same issue, when I added the `kern.maxfilesperproc` everything started working.

Comment: I found that a restart is required for these variables to take effect (as expected). You can confirm that the values have changed by doing `sysctl -a | grep kern.maxfiles`.

Answer (score 8):

To adjust open files limits on a system-wide basis in Mac OS X Yosemite, you must create two configuration files. The first is a property list (aka plist) file in `/Library/LaunchDaemons/limit.maxfiles.plist` that contains the following XML configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
  <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
      <key>Label</key>
        <string>limit.maxfiles</string>
      <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
          <string>launchctl</string>
          <string>limit</string>
          <string>maxfiles</string>
          <string>65536</string>
          <string>65536</string>
        </array>
       <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
      <key>ServiceIPC</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
  </plist>
```

This will set the open files limit to 65536. The second plist configuration file should be stored in `/Library/LaunchDaemons/limit.maxproc.plist` with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple/DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
  <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
      <key>Label</key>
        <string>limit.maxproc</string>
      <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
          <string>launchctl</string>
          <string>limit</string>
          <string>maxproc</string>
          <string>2048</string>
          <string>2048</string>
        </array>
      <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true />
      <key>ServiceIPC</key>
        <false />
    </dict>
  </plist>
```

Both plist files must be owned by `root:wheel` and have permissions `-rw-r--r--`. This permissions should be in place by default, but you can ensure that they are in place by running `sudo chmod 644 <filename>`. While the steps explained above will cause system-wide open file limits to be correctly set upon restart, you can apply them manually by running `launchctl limit`.

In addition to setting these limits at the system level, we recommend setting the at the session level as well by appending the following lines to your `bashrc`, `bashprofile`, or analogous file:

```
ulimit -n 65536
ulimit -u 2048
```

Like the plist files, your bashrc or similar file should have `-rw-r--r--` permissions. At this point, you can restart your computer and enter ulimit -n into your terminal. If your system is configured correctly, you should see that maxfiles has been set to 65536.

Sourced from: http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/tuning/open-files-limit/

Comment: "launchctl limit maxfiles unlimited unlimited ; launchctl limit maxfiles" reports that the maximums are 10240 on my Yosemite 10.10.5 on 2015-09-30, and experimenting around with them seems to show that if you use a larger explicit number, it will be ignored.

Answer (score 5):

Defaults on Yosemite seem to be 12K and 10K:

```
$ sysctl -a | grep kern.maxfiles
kern.maxfiles: 12288
kern.maxfilesperproc: 10240
```

Only setting `kern.maxfiles` in `/etc/sysctl.conf` seems to have solved my problems. `/etc/sysctl.conf` file:

```
kern.maxfiles=24576
```

Comment: exact same values for sierra

Comment: However `launchctl limit maxfiles` gave me this: `maxfiles 256 unlimited`